# C++ Concurrency in Action 9.6 threadpool use thread_local

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, thread-local

It is said that, thread_local,there is one copy per thread.

So if the thread of threadPool(call it A) creat another thread(call it B),  the thread_local variables(local_work_queue) in thread A and B is two different thing。

So I confuse that when the pool summit task in pool thread A(int main()), how it can access the local_work_queue in sub thread B ???  they  are totally irrelevant.

Function submit is in pool thread, and local_work_queue only init in sub thred, so in submit function ,local_work_queue will always nullptr, isn't it?

Below is the code:

```
class thread_pool
{
    typedef std::queue<function_wrapper> local_queue_type;
    static thread_local std::unique_ptr<local_queue_type> local_work_queue;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;`

    thread_pool()
    {
        unsigned const thread_count=std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
        for(unsigned i=0;i<thread_count;++i)
        {
            threads.push_back(
            std::thread(&thread_pool::worker_thread,this,i));
        }
    }

    void worker_thread()
    {
        local_work_queue.reset(new local_queue_type);  //just init in the sub thread
        while(1)
        {
            function_wrapper task;
            if(local_work_queue && !local_work_queue->empty())
            {
                task=std::move(local_work_queue->front());
                local_work_queue->pop();
                task();
            }
            else
            {
                std::this_thread::yield();
            }
        }
    }

    template<typename FunctionType>
    std::future<typename std::result_of<FunctionType()>::type>submit(FunctionType f)
    {
        typedef typename std::result_of<FunctionType()>::type result_type;
        std::packaged_task<result_type()> task(f);
        std::future<result_type> res(task.get_future());
        if(local_work_queue) //function submit is in pool thread, and local_work_queue only init in sub thred, so in this ,local_work_queue will away nullptr, isn't it? so confuse how the code work.
        {
            local_work_queue->push(std::move(task));
        }
        return res;
    }
};

void func()
{
    std::cout<<"test"<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    thread_pool p;
    p.submit(func);
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: question is , the local_work_queue in submit() is always nullptr， so  the threadpool  can't access to push task to  the local_work_queue in subthread.  and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

but you made it static. So it will be accessable through the class? that over rule the thread_local I assume.

see [Storage class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

5) The thread_local keyword is only allowed for objects declared at namespace scope, objects declared at block scope, and static data members. It indicates that the object has thread storage duration. It can be combined with static or extern to specify internal or external linkage (except for static data members which always have external linkage), respectively, but that additional static doesn't affect the storage duration.

its life time is thread local, but linkage is class wide I guess.

Comment: but i test it , i can't be accessable in different thread. the  local_work_queue is always null in pool thread, it can't be step in this:                                                              if(local_work_queue) 
        {
            local_work_queue->push(std::move(task));
        }